# What legal aspects should one consider when creating a constructed language?

Tags: legal

Constructed languages, like everything, is an intellectual property, and most countries worldwide do care about protecting the rights of the owners.

If I'm about to create a new conlang, should I consider any existing patents?

My common sense suggests me that something is obvious here:

- entirely copying someone else's writing system would certainly constitute a copyright infringement;
- lots of things are public domain, e.g. SVO/OVS clause order or the Latin alphabet;

…but I'm totally lost about the case if *some* aspect(s) of existing works can be incidentally copied or deliberately borrowed.

**Where should I start here?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> If I'm about to create a new conlang, should I consider any existing patents?

No. It is conceivable that conlangs might be patentable under US law, but none so far have been.

> entirely copying someone else's writing system would certainly constitute a copyright infringement;

Probably not. Again, it might infringe a patent, but there are very few patents on writing systems. Copying a specific *font* or typeface would constitute copyright infringement, but not copying the writing system in abstract.

> Where should I start here?

I'd start by reviewing [Sai's talk at LCC 6 on the legal status of conlangs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqNis7y0hA8), and the accompanying [slides](http://conlang.org/cms/wp-content/uploads/LCC6_Sai.pdf) and [legal memo](http://conlang.org/cms/wp-content/uploads/Dentons-Conlang-Memo-public-version.pdf).

You might also review [the Language Creation Society's involvement in the Axanar case](https://conlang.org/axanar/) regarding whether or not Paramount "owns" Klingon.

Comment: Re fonts, one thing people usually don't realize is that it's not the visual design of the characters that's protected, but rather the _code_ that implements a particular instantiation thereof. Which is why it's legal (albeit ethically questionable) to make a ripoff font by tracing over letters and re-doing the kerning instructions etc.